# How to check for current CMake build type in C++?

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

A little background: I'm writing a game in SFML and I want certain lines of code to be ommitted in Release build. I want to check during compile time for build type, so that is doesn't impact game's performance.

```cpp
void Tile::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const {
    states.transform *= getTransform();
    target.draw(m_sprite, states);
    #if(DEBUG)
        target.draw(m_collision_shape, states);
    #endif
}
```

I'm relatively new to CMake world, so I don't even know if it's possible.

**EDIT:**
It's probably worth mentioning I use ninja as a build system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's how you might do it in general (working for any generator):

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "DEBUG=$<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,1,0>")
```

If you need it for every target you can use the following in the top CMake file (in case you have multiple with `add_subdirectory`) and *before* (it is not required but it is less confusing) you created a target. Also as Alex Reinking rightfully corrected we can use a simpler condition, because `$<CONFIG:Debug>` already gives `1` or `0`.

So applying everything described above we get something like this:

```
add_compile_definitions("DEBUG=$<CONFIG:Debug>")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

Comment: That's neat! Thanks!
Now what if I would like it to be available in every target in my project? Do I have to specify it manually for each?

Comment: `$<CONFIG:Debug>` already returns `1` or `0`, so the `$<IF:>` genex is unnecessary.

Comment: I'm very tempted to downvote for the use of directory commands here. They should not be used in new code because of their many vexing behaviors and low debuggability

Comment: @AlexReinking thanks for the correction. I kept 2 versions with one general for the reference and different values. As to `add_compile_definitions`: you can downvote however you want, it won't change the usefulness of these commands. In fact, that's exactly what the OP asked for. So I don't get what is your problem here. You don't like it, don't use it. But don't try to impose your opinion on other people.

Comment: It is exactly what my project needs. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Add a macro from cmake in your code:

```
// CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(your_game yoru_soruces.c)
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    target_compile_definitions(your_game PRIVATE DEBUG=1)
else()
    target_compile_definitions(your_game PRIVATE DEBUG=0)
endif()
```

You could also instead use the standard macro `NDEBUG`, `#if !NDEBUG`, however it's better to leave it for asserts only. `NDEBUG` is not defined for `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` builds.

Comment: It is only a partial solution for single-config generators. Won't work on others, like MSVS, Ninja MC etc. Better use generator expressions for that.